# Self-study: Comparing Uniform and Normal CDF/quantiles for a given range

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, quantiles, uniform-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

Not sure if the title is perfect. Nevertheless, there are two persons drawing $\alpha$. ‘A’ draws from $N(0,1)$ and ‘B’ from $U(-2\sqrt{2\pi}, 2\sqrt{2\pi})$. For which person is it more likely that the equation $$x^2 + \alpha x +\ln{2}=0$$ has real roots?

I am stuck at checking the inequality,

$$\sqrt{\frac{\ln 2}{2\pi}} \gtreqqless 2\Phi\big(2\sqrt{\ln 2}\big)-1$$

Obviously there should be a way to check this without having to calculate it. I tried using the expression for $\int_{-\infty}^{2\sqrt{\ln 2}} \phi(x)$ (hoping to to make use of the $\sqrt{2\pi}$ from there) but couldn’t find the way out.

Comment: My inclination would be to consider a series for $\Phi$. e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function

Comment: thanks so much for that reference. i think that does it in the most easy way.